# TypeError: filePaths.map is not a function in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, puppeteer

i wanna use the file path into upload a file,when use the normal path it is work but i wanna try with use a globat file path in the console

[the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1ZxG.jpg)

```
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForFileChooser(),
    page.click('div[data-testid=new-post-button]')
]);

await fileChooser.accept(''+filealamat+'');    // <<------ into here
```

and this is the procces to get filepath

```
var filealamat;

if (process.platform !== 'darwin') { 

    dialog.showOpenDialog({ 
    
        title: 'pilih file', 
        defaultPath: path.join(__dirname, '../assets/'), 
        buttonLabel: 'UPLOAD', 
        filters: [ 
            { 
                name: 'image Files', 
                extensions: ['txt', 'docx','jpg','jpeg','png'] 
            }, 
        ], 
        properties: ['openFile'] 
        
    }).then(file => { 
        console.log(file.canceled); 
        if (!file.canceled) { 
            filealamat = file.filePaths[0].toString(); 
            console.log(filealamat); 
        }   
    }).catch(err => { 
        console.log(err)  
    }); 

}
```

is that possible?? or should i use extras npm??

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please avoid posting pictures of the issue and instead descripe it or paste the show code in a stack snippet. The question should be understandable even when the url of the image has vanished.